# How often documents need to be relocated in mongo 4.4 as their size increases

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I am using arrays in mongo 4.4 documents. I want to know how often documents need to be relocated in mongo 4.4 as the size increases. As usePowerOf2Sizes and paddingFactor are removed from mongo version 4.4.
I am worried that if during every push to array of every document, that document is relocated then fragmentation will become a big problem.
Thanks